# Excel VBA insert fails after rows have been deleted on worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a simple helper function to copy and insert an arbitrary number of rows on a given worksheet.

```
Public Sub insertRows(tgtWorksheet As String, R As Integer, NumRows As Integer)
    'Statements added for error checking'
    Debug.Print ("Inserting " & NumRows & " rows in '" & tgtWorksheet & "' by copying row " & insertRow)
    copyRng = Worksheets(tgtWorksheet).Rows(insertRow).EntireRow
    pasteRng = Range(Worksheets(tgtWorksheet).Cells(insertRow, 1), Worksheets(tgtWorksheet).Cells(insertRow + NumRows - 1, 1)).EntireRow
    'End statements added for error checking'

    Worksheets(tgtWorksheet).Rows(insertRow).EntireRow.Copy
    Range(Worksheets(tgtWorksheet).Cells(insertRow, 1), Worksheets(tgtWorksheet).Cells(insertRow + NumRows - 1, 1)).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

This function supports database functionality to read and write externally hosted records to a worksheet. Each row in the excel table has a mix of raw input cells and formulas.  The database only stores the raw input cells, so when I load data from the database, I identify the first empty row and use it to create the needed number of template rows to store the new data.

The problem is, after I've run this successfully and then I delete the rows from the target worksheet that have the same row number as the target for my insert, when I try to run the function again I get a `Run-time error '-2147417848 (80010108) Method 'Insert of object 'Range' failed`

When I interrogate the two ranges `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(tgtWorksheet).Rows(R).EntireRow` and `Range(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(tgtWorksheet).Cells(R, 1),ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(tgtWorksheet).Cells(R + NumRows - 1, 1)).EntireRow`

they look exactly the same in cases where the macro fails as when it succeeds.

I am not using filters or pivot tables in my tgtWorksheet.  Somehow that delete action is confusing the macro.

How can I troubleshoot this?

---

### Edit - Detailed error traceback

Some additional information here:

The calling database download function calls insertRows with the line:

```
Call insertRows(tgtWorksheet, insertRow, NumRows)
```

Initially, I open the workbook and call the function to download one record of data.  The function runs without error. If I pause directly before the copy line I get the following image in my immediate/locals:

[image: immediate/locals 1]

I can run this an arbitrary number of times with different parameters, adding different data and different numbers of rows successfully.

At some point, I have enough data inserted that my first empty row is row 50.  If I go to the tgtworksheet and delete row 50, and then run it again, I get an error.  (Note that in this case row 51 is element by element exactly the same as row 50.  It's also element by element exactly the same row as row 44 is in the initial run above. I have some unknown number of blank template rows at the bottom of my data, and I use the insertRows function to make sure there are enough spacer rows).

[image]

The immediate/locals window looks exactly the same here, despite now getting the insert error.

[image]

Comment: I am slightly confused? What rows are you deleting? BTW your code can be written in a better way.. . (I will address that later)  Can you explain it a little more as to what exactly is happening? Perhaps some example?

Comment: Depending on how you delete the cells and rerun the function. I am assuming your original assignment to `tgtWorksheet` is not re-set, in which case it puts the original range into an `undefined` state because it has now been deleted.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I have added detailed immediate/locals window info in my post.  The broader database function is 150+ lines.  I am not able to recreate the issue by simply running insertRows in a fresh workbook, so my guess is there is some sort of implicit protection of the rows that is arising.

Comment: @AJD Thanks for the suggestion.  In the locals window the range is not undefined when I attempt the insert.  See the last pic in my updated edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I determined that the root of the problem was that the sheet was being temporarily protected within the larger database macro.

The code that is now working for me is

```
Public Sub insertRows(tgtWorksheet As String, insertRow As Integer, numRows As Integer)
    With Worksheets(tgtWorksheet)
        .Unprotect
        .Rows(insertRow).Copy
        .Range(insertRow + 1 & ":" & insertRow + numRows).Insert (xlDown)
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```